# Story about an assassin who is very much prepared when things turn against him?

Tags: story-identification

In my childhood I read an SF story about an assassin (and/or thief?) who successfully completes an assignment (murder?) at the beginning of the story. Upon coming back to his home/apartment he notices something unusual (I think he believes he is being set up/tried to be getting rid of?) and leaves.
He then starts a number of carefully pre-planned actions to deal with such a case, eliminating the threats to him, transferring money/funds, etc and setting up a new identity (as far as I remember). I do not remember how the story continues but have a vague believe that it takes on a completely different direction from that on?

The name of the protagonist might possibly be "Kees van Lee-Locklin" or something similar, maybe? I could not find anything regarding that name, so am not sure if I am not mixing up things, though...

Comment: You say this is a SF story but what makes it science fictional? Could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: I do not remember much more than this, though am pretty sure it was an SF story... unfortunately do not remember how the story continues, maybe there if takes on more of an SF character? Probably was in the 90s or so that I read it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kees vaan Loo-Macklin is the protagonist of Alan Dean Foster's [*The Man Who Used the Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?18365).

Kees is a 22-year-old minor criminal (83rd class illegal) at the start of the novel.  After killing (his first) a jeweler who has refused to take protection, he gets warned on his way back to his apartment that someone is there.

It has already been made clear that Kees is careful and prepared; he planned and extensively practiced a method of killing the jeweler faster than the jeweler could react and trigger the defensive weapons of his shop.  He has his own apartment bugged and stops on the way home to gather the tools he needs before walking into a trap.

He has anticipated that his employer (not his boss!) might decide he's a danger and try to kill him, and has prepared to handle that, from eliminating the immediate threat to going into hiding and then going on a counter-offensive.

[image: Paperback cover of "The Man Who Used the Universe"]

Comment: Super, that's the story I was looking for, thanks!